# Is this set always closed?

Tags: general-topology

I'm not sure if I am overthinking this problem, or it actually is somewhat
tricky. Given a set of reals $S$, let $I = \{t \in \mathbb{R} |
  \exists s \in S. |t-s| \leq 4\}.$ I'm trying to figure out if this
set is necessarily closed. I can see that we can generalize the set to be
$$\bigcup_{s \in S} [s-4,s+4],$$
Although I am looking for a set $S$ that makes this turn into a somewhat open
set. I considered originally $S = \mathbb{N},$ But that did not quite work for
me. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $I$ seems to be all of the points which are less than or equal to a distance of four from any given point in $S$. Symbolically we have
$$I = \bigcup_{|x|\le 4} \left\{s+x : s \in S \right\}$$

Basically, I comes from putting a closed interval of width $8$ centered at each point of $s$ and then taking their union.

Let's look at an example.

If $S$ is an open interval, say $S = (3,4)$, then
$$I = \bigcup_{|x|\le 4} \left\{s+x : s \in (3,4) \right\}=(-1,0)$$

In this case I is open.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try $S=(0,1)$ (or any other open interval).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $S = [0,1)$. Then $I = \bigcup_{s \in [0,1)} [s-4,s+4] = [-4,5)$.